# Changing order of tabs in Ext.tab.panel without cut-paste of code manually

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am writing a code as below in Sencha Touch 2.3. Is there a way to bring the nestedlist to show up before the formpanel (it is currently after) without cutting and pasting the code manually? something like each of TabPanel's component having a Rank or an Order property that I can set? Thanks

```
    Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {

                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                cls: 'home',
                ...

            },


            {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                ..
            },
            {
                xtype: 'nestedlist',
                ..
            }
      ]});
```

Comment: no, there is no property for that. why can't you copy and paste the parts, should be no problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it at [definition time](http://extjs.eu/ext-touch-component-life-cycle/) but you could do it at runtime by calling [`tabpanel.insert(newIndex, nestedList)`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.Container-event-move), where newIndex would be most likely `1` and `nestedList` is the reference to the already existing nested list.